# Ran this script, recoverable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I ran this script: https://gist.github.com/mesuutt/2f27d78d32fc31d477293155a24b7e3f

and I thought it would deploy my static site blog to my GitHub pages account, but instead deleted almost all of my personal files.

Is there a way to recover this or find the missing links to the indexed files?

Comment: Recover from your backups.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have backups, then you have just learned how important regular backups are! You have also learned that it is always good to inspect scripts you "download" from the Internet.

So, turn your computer off NOW. Get a liveCD with linux onto a USB dongle, plug in a USB hard drive or use a second internal hard drive, install testdisk and attempt to recover what you can.

testdisk will recover what it can ... Good luck!

Clarification: You have to turn your computer off, because you might be overwriting files as we speak. You need a second hard drive (USB/internal) to copy the data testdisk has recovered.